# jQuery slide toggle fires twice on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I prevent toggle from sliding twice on double click?

I have a button that triggers a slide toggle. It toggles fine if the button is clicked once but if the button is clicked twice the slide toggle slides out then immediately slides back in.

How can I get the slide toggle to stay out even on double click?

Code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ljgqjo

JS:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('#one').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#two').toggle('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 800, function(){
            

        });
    });
});
```

```css
.container{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#one{
  background:blue;
   width:300px;
  height:200px;
}
#two{
  background:purple;
   width:300px;
  display:none;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me to slide</button>
<div class="container">
  <div id="one">
</div>
  <div id="two">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/nya99njz/2/

```js
var sliding = false;
$('button').on('click dblclick', function(){
  if(!sliding){
    sliding = true;
    $('#one').fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $('#two').toggle('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 800, function(){
        sliding = false;
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.container{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#one{
  background:blue;
   width:300px;
  height:200px;
}
#two{
  background:purple;
   width:300px;
  display:none;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me to slide</button>
<div class="container">
  <div id="one">
</div>
  <div id="two">
</div>
</div>
```

Instead of `click` use `dblclick`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I need it to work on single and double click, that only works on double click.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question?

Comment: Sure, as it is now the toggle slides out and then immediately  snaps back in on double click. I need the purple to stay out on click and on double click, it shouldn't slide back unless the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Can you update your answer here so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: So if I was to use this for say 50 or 60 different elements would I need to create a new variable for each? Or can I just declare sliding once and use it again and again for different elements?

Comment: @Mia You don't have to create 50 or 60 variable, this code will work with all the different elements. Just you need to replace `id` with `classname` or some element `tagname`.

Answer (score 4):

Set a flag for tracking whether your animation is running.  Check if it is set before allowing the click action to have any effect.  Unset it once your animation is done:

```
var animating = false;
$('button').on('click', function(){
    if(!animating){
        animating = true;
        $('#one').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#two').toggle('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 800, function(){
                animating = false;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

This has the additional benefit of protecting against triple clicks (and quadruple clicks, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line

`$('button').on('click', function(){`

To

`$('button').on('click dblclick', function(){`

Then it will do the same thing for click and double click.